# Problem with HTML in new user activity dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, activity-dropdown

The new user activity dropdown is useful. I rather like it.

It does, however, appear to have a small bug.

The element `html body.question-page div.container div#header div#topbar div#hlinks span#hlinks-user div.profile-popup div.profile-wrapper div.profile-stats div div.recent-rep-wrapper table tbody tr td div.profile-overflow a` (CSS hierarchy notation) appears — for some entries — to have a class name equal to the entry's title.

This isn't the case for all entries. For example:

```
<tr>
<td class="profile-table-rep-col1" title="1 reputation was lost in the last 1 day">-1</td>
<td>
<div class="profile-overflow">
<a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/5532725/sql-failing-to-calling-fields-correctly">Sql failing to calling fields correctly</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

but

```
<tr>
<td class="profile-table-rep-col1" title="You reached the reputation cap for this post">0</td>
<td>
<div class="profile-overflow">
<a class="Leap year date counting code doesn't work" href="/questions/5507735/leap-year-date-counting-code-doesnt-work/5520350#5520350">Leap year date counting code doesn't work</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

In some cases (specifically, where one of the words in the class matches an actual class, such as `.date`), this is affecting display:

[Example of broken CSS in user activity dropdown http://oi51.tinypic.com/302mdj9.jpg](http://oi51.tinypic.com/302mdj9.jpg)

Comment: I like how the Leap year leaps out - i reckon it's not a bug :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional parameters bit me here, this was using an improper overload for rendering answer links...it'll be fixed in a build going out right now.

Comment: Cheers Nick. :)